# Como pegar um nome dentro de uma string em php?

Tags: php, string

```
$resultado = "spawn needle /var/www/html/trabalho/arquivo/emboss/needle/alvos.txt /var/www/html/trabalho/arquivo/emboss/needle/modelos.txt Needleman-Wunsch global alignment of two sequences Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Gap opening penalty [10.0]: 10.0 Gap extension penalty [0.5]: 0.5 Output alignment [hba_human.needle]:"
```

Como pegar em php uma parte da minha string onde tenho **[hba_human.needle]** sendo que o hba_human seria o nome do arquivo, então como posso pegar o que está entre as **[ ]** e tem extensao **.needle** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**veja funcionando no ideone**](https://ideone.com/z1DCs5)

Use   [`strripos`](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strripos.php) Encontra a posição da última ocorrência de uma string case-insensitive em uma string. Procure as posições de `[` e de `]`

Depois use [`substr`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.substr.php) — Retorna uma parte de uma string

```
$resultado = "spawn needle /var/www/html/trabalho/arquivo/emboss/needle/alvos.txt /var/www/html/trabalho/arquivo/emboss/needle/modelos.txt Needleman-Wunsch global alignment of two sequences Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Warning: Unknown swissprot line type ' ' Gap opening penalty [10.0]: 10.0 Gap extension penalty [0.5]: 0.5 Output alignment [hba_human.needle]:";

$posInicio  = strripos($resultado, "[");

$posFim  = strripos($resultado, "]");

//quantidade de caracteres que serão extraídos contados a partir da posição inicial
$quant= ($posFim-$posInicio-1);

echo substr($resultado, $posInicio+1, $quant);
```